# Apache 2.4 (win2k12) not answering on port 8080 for vhosts

Tags: port, vhosts, windows-server-2012-r2, apache2.4

**Problem:**
I want to switch from IIS to Apache for different reasons, as I also want to run other stuff in parallel I need Apache to be configured on a different port than 80. I run multiple domains with one IP and so I configured the vhosts. When I set the port on 80 everything works fine, as soon as I switch to another port I either get only the "default" vhost or in some configurations a 404.

**What I tried/have done:**
- Firewall is configured to accept 8080 as port and allow httpd.exe itself.
- netstat only lists httpd.exe as listener on the configured ports I tried.
- IIS is not installed anymore

Below is the configuration which works, just fine.
- When I switch every port 80 to 8080 is does not work
- When I remove the explicit IP's in the "Listen" to "Listen 8080" is does not work

Any ideas why port 8080 (I also tried 8000) does not work?

Thanks

etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       srv.mydomain.com
::1             srv.mydomain.com
```

conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "c:/folder/htdocs/foo/www"
   ServerName www.foo.com
   ServerAlias foo.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "c:/folder/htdocs/foo/www"
   ServerName www.foo.net
   ServerAlias foo.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "c:/folder/htdocs/foo/static"
   ServerName static.foo.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "c:/folder/htdocs/foo/blog"
   ServerName blog.foo.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "c:/folder/htdocs/bar/www"
   ServerName www.bar.net
   ServerAlias bar.net *.bar.net
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf

```
Listen <ipv4>:80
Listen [<ipv6>]:80

ServerName srv.bar.net

DocumentRoot "c:/folder/htdocs"
<Directory "c:/folder/htdocs">    
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:8080>` and add `Listen *:8080`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11227894)

Comment: erm, yes it is an answer to the question: because that is what he has done wrong. You are  saying that I "phrased" my answer in a questioning voice. this is still an answer

Comment: In that case, your answer may help others better if you [edit] to phrase it without the questioning voice.

Comment: please do not edit my comments, you do not have my permission and it is incidentally a breach of copyright - which I am not in the habit of waiving - if this means you decide to take my (correct) answer down I leave that to your discretion, but I hope not because it'd be an utter shame.. additionally: please stop "endlessly administering" my perfectly good answer to get gems and instead put some effort into getting in touch with the chap who hasn't accept it.

Comment: Regarding editing, I'll refer you to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).  Regarding copyright, I'll refer you to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).  You're clearly more knowledgeable about this subject than I, so I hope that you'll continue contributing to SO.  But if you aren't willing to abide by the site's terms of service, then this may not be the right forum for you.